# How to extract numeric values from string?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm having a vector like this **Vector = "a:2.34;b:1.24;c:0.67"**. How can I get the value which is **2.34,1.24,0.67**? I don't want to use any split functionality here. I'm using C#.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to avoid split functions; is this an homework?

Comment: What exactly counts as "split functionality"? Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expression to do this. Although this pattern is very naively implemented, it is a start. I've used Tuple instead of Vector, but you can easily change that yourself.

```
    static readonly Regex VectorRegex = new Regex(@"a:(?<A>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+);b:(?<B>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+);c:(?<C>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static Tuple<double, double, double> ParseVector(string input)
    {
        var m = VectorRegex.Match(input);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            double a, b, c;
            a = double.Parse(m.Groups["A"].Value, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            b = double.Parse(m.Groups["B"].Value, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            c = double.Parse(m.Groups["C"].Value, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            return new Tuple<double, double, double>(a, b, c);
        }
        else
            throw new FormatException("Invalid input format");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not want a split functionality?

You could iterate over the vector and separate on every colon with `strtok()` ( assuming you use C/C++).

You could also consider using a KV map.